# How would the "Name [function] not defined" error be solved in my situation?

Tags: python, python-import

To keep my program neat, I am putting most of my functions in a separate file. The secondary file is in the same directory as the main file. I am positive that I imported the secondary file properly:
`from file2 import *`

The desired function is defined at the very beginning of the second file, so why am I still getting this error?

Edit: It seems I have made it unclear where the problem is coming from. I have imported file2.py to main.py, as shown in the original description. The import was done at the very beginning of main.py, which is why I was confused about this behavior. To clear up any misunderstandings, I will provide an example that should reproduce the problem.

Here is the code for main.py (note: when the program is executed, it starts here):

```py
# main.py

from os import system, name
from file2 import *

# welcome function obtains username
def welcome() :
    print("Welcome to UNO! Please enter your name:")
    global username
    username = str(input(""))

    # if the user's name is valid, continue. if not, restart
    if username.isalnum() == True :
        setup()

    else :
        print("Something went wrong. Make sure to include only alphanumeric characters in your name.")
        welcome()

# setup function defines game rules
# user can only enter number a number and the number cannot be more than 4 nor less than 1
def setup() :
    print("Enter how many CPUS you would like to play against (1-3):")
    global numCPUs
    numCPUs = input("")

    # determine if the user input is valid. if not, restart
    if numCPUs >= "1" and numCPUs <= "3" :
                print("Hello there, " + username + """! In case you may have forgotten how to play UNO, here is a quick refresher:

        1. Each player is given 7 random cards to start. The cards in your hand are visible to you only. Likewise, your opponents can see only their cards.
    
        2. Once the game starts, a card is drawn at random from what remains in the deck after the initial serve and is laid on the table.
    
        3. Once it becomes your turn to play, you will choose a card from your hand that depicts either the same number or color (or both) as the previous played card. You may also use a wild card if you have one. If you do not have a playable card, you must draw from the deck until you acquire a playable card (fun, right?).
    
Ready? (y/es, n/o):""")
        usrInput = input("").lower()
        
        # determine if the user is ready to play
        if usrInput == "y" :
            initialize() # function called from file2.py

        else :
            os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear") # cross platform clear screen code
            welcome()

    else :
        print("Something went wrong. Please enter a number between 1-3.")
        setup()

# call the welcome function to start the process
welcome()
```

Here is the code for file2.py:

```py
# file2.py (debug purposes)

from main import * # import everything from main

def initialize() :
    if int(main.numCPUs) == 1 :
        print(main.numCPUs)
    elif int(main.numCPUs) == 2 :
        print(main.numCPUs)
    else :
        print(main.numCPUs)
```

The error specifically reads "name 'initialize' is not defined"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? What program are you executing... main.py? It doesn't appear to import anything. You aren't showing a `card_handler.py` module, what does it do? If main.py wants to use `initialize`, it needs to `from file2 import *`. Not the other way around.

Comment: You are not importing it "properly", PEP8 discourages importing like this: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Comment: @André That's a good point, but to be clear, it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I agree with tdelaney, plus there's a syntax error, `{` instead of `:`. If you still need help, you'll need to make a [mre]. BTW, for more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea `:` is proper syntax for code blocks in python, not `{ }`

Comment: I improved the formatting of the original post. I hope the problem is much more clear now

Comment: @Gabe I believe wjandrea was pointing out that your example file2 has `{` instead of the correct syntax `:` at the start of the initialize function

Comment: @nigh_anxiety that was my mistake. thank you and @wjandrea for pointing that out. i would like to make it clear that `:` was used in all such instances in the real program

Comment: If I understand the updated question correctly (again, please add the [full error](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)), this is a duplicate of [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](/q/6523791/4518341), with the added caveat that you have a [circular import](/q/744373/what-happens-when-using-mutual-or-circular-cyclic-imports).

Comment: @wjandrea The error in full (in visual studio) reads "name 'initialize' is not defined". I hope this helps.

Comment: @Gabe Oh, it's from the linter? We thought it was a Python error. What happens when you try running your code?

Comment: Classic circular import problem. Don't use circular imports. (Don't use `import *` either, but *definitely* don't use circular imports.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function `initialize` defined in a module, you need to import **from that module** in order for that function to be visible in another module.

In other words, you imports are backwards.

Instead of `from main import *` in `file2.py`, you need to modify `main.py`:

```
from file2 import initialize

...

if usrInput == "y" :
    initialize() # this returns the error
```

(Or `from file2 import *` to import all symbols instead of just `initialize`, but note that using `import *` is discouraged for many reasons (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386740/6340496), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386943/6340496)))